# Why is autologon in Windows 7 a security risk

Tags: windows-7, security, login

If I set my Windows 7 account to automatically logon so I don't have to type a password, and I don't have to click my username on the logon screen, I heard it's a security risk.

From [Windows 7 Auto Login](http://on10.net/blogs/sarahintampa/Tip-Auto-Login-Your-Windows-7-User-Account/):

> Although I don’t personally recommend
>   this, there are some people out there
>   who don’t want to bother with using a
>   password to protect their Windows user
>   account. Of course, using a password
>   in Windows isn’t required, only
>   suggested. But even if you don’t fill
>   one in, you still have to click your
>   user icon to start the login process.
>
> An easier way - although again much
>   less secure - is to enable auto-logins
>   for your Windows PC. This is possible
>   in Windows 7, as it was in prior
>   versions, but it takes a little
>   finagling to do so. (And for good
>   reason, darn it.)

What is risky about it besides people being able to logon locally?  Does it make it easier for hackers to logon remotely?

Comment: This is sort of like asking 'what's the risk of jay-walking besides being flattened by a motor vehicle?'

Comment: No, it's like asking "what are the risks of jay-walking besides other cars."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the security risk it is referring to - anyone who obtains physical access to the machine is able to log on and access any of your data. If your computer is in a safe place and that isn't an issue for you, there's no need to worry about it!

Comment: Technically, if someone had physical access to your computer and they really wanted your data, they could get it without knowing your password. But by that time you have bigger things to worry about.

Comment: Sure they can get my data and all, doesn't mean they will be able to read any of it. Encryption is king.

Comment: If it's encrypted, then it's a different issue (since they still need a password, they just put it in earlier).

Comment: My point was that if a complete stranger has physical access to your computer, your password is the thing you should be least worried about. ;)

Answer (score 4):

No, remote hackers won't be able to do anything more than they otherwise could. The risk is only local, as you already mentioned.

If your computer is on your desk at home and you know who is around, then use autologin.

If it's a laptop and/or work computer then don't use autologin.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious risk that someone can walk up to your computer and use it, there is another minor security risk.  When you set autologon, your password is now on the computer.  It is encrypted and theoretically safe, but there's always a chance that it can be discovered.

Comment: The password is already on the computer. If it wasn't, the computer wouldn't be able to check if it's correct. I assumed Windows just had an "auto-login" flag, but I guess having an unencrypted file with the password in it would work too.. :-\

Comment: @Brendan Long: There are ways to store a "password" on a computer so that it can not be recovered without brute-force attacking it.  This is different from the ways that, say, your browser stores passwords for your favourite websites, where the cleartext of the password is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The #1 security risk for companies is insiders.  Often it is dissatisfied employees.  Let's think of you personally as a company.  Ever had a friend go to the dark side and start abusing you in some way.  Why wouldn't that person wreck your computer or steal your data.

Now to this thought about it (your data) being encrypted being security.  From inside your computer as a legitimate user, it's not encrypted.  That's why you can use it.

So, let's do steps on how you might get hacked:
1.  I decide I hate you
2.  I am nice to you so you won't cut me off
3.  I logon and change your password.  You'll never know because you don't use it anyway.
4.  I remote your computer as you.
5.  Now I can do evil things to you to my heart's content...

So, yes!  I'm saying that you are taking a risk.